# Continuous function over a metric space.

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

I want to show that $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert :(\mathbb{R}^{d},\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{2})\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$  is continuous.

Which means, that if I take $x_0 = (a_0,...,a_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d\;$ I need to show that $\forall \varepsilon >0\;$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x=(b_1,...,b_d)$ such that $\left\Vert x-x_{0}\right\Vert _{2}<\delta$ we get $\left|\left\Vert x\right\Vert -\left\Vert x_{0}\right\Vert \right|<\varepsilon$

I'm having trouble forming a proof. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the reverse triangle inequality and equivalence of norms on $\mathbb{R}^d$. See Wikipedia for the reverse triangle inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality, this also includes a proof) and http://mathonline.wikidot.com/equivalence-of-norms-in-a-finite-dimensional-linear-space for equivalence of norms (in fact, we only need the part of the proof about $\exists D>0: ||\cdot||\leq D||\cdot||_*$). By equivalence of norms, there exists $C>0$ such that $||\cdot||\leq C||\cdot||_2$.

In particular, choose $\delta = \epsilon/C$. Then $| ||x||-||x_0||| \leq ||x-x_0|| \leq C||x-x_0||_2 <C\delta = \epsilon.$

Comment: What?
$||x-x_0|| <\delta $ Doesn't help. notice that i need to take $||x-x_0||_2 <\delta $

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that $||\cdot||$ isn't the same as $||\cdot||_2,$ I thought you simply omitted the subscript 2. I edited my answer, equivalence of norms on finite-dimensional spaces fixes this problem.